# Why my controller asking for full path instead of direct return statement without parameter in mv3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In a controller I added some logic, right clicked on that controller and added one partial view. Why `return View()` not going to return my added view. I checked that right clicking on the controller when click on go to view -> showing that view. But by using code `return view()` not returning my view. Its asking full path of the view.

```
 return View("/Areas/Admin/Views/Search/ShowResult.ascx"); -->working
 return View(); -->not working
```

I need to eliminate full path. Please tell me why my view not returning using this return View().

EDIT :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("search", "index", new { Area = "admin", Controller = "search" }, new { style = "text-decoration: none" })%>
```

AdminAreaRegistration.cs

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName {
            get {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { area = "admin",action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Global.ascx.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {


            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
}
```

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ShowResult(FormCollection collection)
        {
 return View("/Areas/Admin/Views/Search/ShowResult.ascx"); //working properly
return View();//not working any one tell me ...
}
```

return View();---------------not working asking full path.please tell me

Thanks

Comment: Can u try `return Partial()` instead of `return View()` .? Just an experiment.

Comment: What's the name of your Controller and Action method ?

Comment: Did you register you routes for areas in AreaRegistration file (inside area folder)? What is output of view engine error which search pathes it checked? (like searched locations ~/Views/Shared ~Views/Admin/Shared etc)

Comment: Controller name :SearchController,ActionName :ShowResult

Comment: @STO,in AreaRegistration file given default route only.

Comment: anyone tell me solution for this?

Comment: anyone tell me solution for this i am trying to resolve this from last day.I need to avoid hardcode paths while returning of view.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the name of the ActionMethod and view name be identical for you to use return View()? Your ActionMethod name is ShowResult() and the view is named "Test.aspx". The view engine is unable to make that link therefore it asks for a fully qualified name to use return view you have to change the method name to Test or the view name to ShowResult.

Comment: sorry for testing i given test.aspx like that in above.I created View name as ShowResult.ascx only.not returning to view by using return view();

Comment: please give me solution for this i am trying for that from last day onwards